# Angularjs Performing Loop Delete and Splice the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to a delete button that will delete all selected datas from table, which i wish that i can splice the array at the same time.

**HTML**

```
<button class="ui red small labeled icon button right floated" type="button" ng-click="Delete()">Delete</button>

 <table class="ui fixed single line celled blue table compact ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="width-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="selectedAll()" /></th>
        <th class="width-100">Date</th>
        <th class="width-120">Qoute no</th>
        <th class="width-70">Item</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in Tablelist | paginate:rowsPerPage track by $index" ng-class="ColoringRow(x)">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.selected"></td>
        <td>{{x.date}}</td>
        <td></i>{{x.quote_no}}</td>
        <td>{{x.item_no}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**JS**

```
 $scope.Delete = function(){
     for (var k = 0; k < $scope.Tablelist.length; k++){
        if($scope.Tablelist[k].selected == true){
          var id = $index;
          var docno = $scope.Tablelist[k].quote_no;
          $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: "api/purchase/purchase.php",
          data: {
            modul: 'PRICE',
            action: 'delete',
            docno: docno,
            id: id,
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          }
        }).then(function(response){
          if (response.data == 1){
            $scope.Tablelist.splice(id,1)
          }else {
            console.log("failed delete1");
          }
        }, function(response){
          console.log("failed delete");
        })
        }
      }

    }
```

So how can i get the value of the `$index` from angular `track by $index` in `var id = $index;`

Or is there any more easy ways?

Comment: just a thought, rather than `$scope.TableList.splice()` , can you make the ajax call to repopulate `TableList` after successful delete?

Comment: this is one of the option, but if the list of data is big, it would be some issue with performance right?

Comment: yes, it would be. If you have already checked for selected values, wouldn't be `var id = k` when you loop though the array.

Comment: Hmmm, is it same between $track by angular and the k in my looping?

Comment: i think you also can use IndexOf method

Comment: Tried using the indexOf but it gave me -1 result for every data, maybe i am doing something wrong.